# I am not getting jwt token

Tags: node.js, express

I have a microservice that has a usermanagement service. In the service I created a .env file and stored my secret. It however does not a give a token when I bring up the services using docker-compose up.

[image]

(I have required doenv in my index.js, I have installed jwt, The .env is inside the service folder not the docker-compose folder)

kindly advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json()` only takes one argument, but you're currently passing in two.

Change `res.status(201).json(admin, token)` to `res.status(201).json({ admin, token })`